# Open source WMS that supports spatial aggregation and image tiling

Tags: wms, wms-time

I have daily raster data in geotiff/netcdf format for the world in 10x10 lat-long degrees tiles. Every day, new data is coming in. I want to let people access this data using WMS through a GIS portal.

Ideally, I want to use open source solutions to do so, and therefore would like to make use of e.g. thredds data server. However, Rich Signell pointed out that thredds doesn't support spatial aggregation and image tiling.

So my question is:

What open source WMS software is out there that support file aggregation (multiple files to cover spatially the world) as well as temporal (daily new data)?

Current structure of the data:

I would like to keep the 10x10degrees data tiles, so to cover the world I would have ~648 (360*180)/(10*10) netcdf files. I'm only interested in terrestrial area so realistically there will be less than ~200 netcdf files, each with a grid resolution of 250meter.

I don't want to merge these tiles to create one large file for the entire world, so spatially I have many netcdf files. The reason for this is that one file to cover the entire world becomes too large.

Temporal I would have many files as each day new data comes in for the world. Right now I store this data in separate temporal netcdf files. There is no need to keep this data in temporal separate files for each tile, I could every day write to an existing data netcdf file and add the current data.

In the end I would like to have data presented in a GIS portal such that people can browse to an area of interest and browse through the different time layers using a slider or by entering start and end data.

Is it feasible what I would like to do with anything else than ArcGIS database?

Comment: geoserver imagemosaic with temporal dimension - https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=geoserver+imagemosaic+with+temporal+dimension